# VHDL: OR-ing bits of a vector together

Tags: vhdl

I want to OR the bits of a vector together. So say I have a vector called `example(23 downto 0)` and I want to OR all the bits into another vector, is there any way to do this that does not involve going `example(0) or example(1) or ...example(23)`?

Comment: Could you simply compare to zero instead?  That would have the same effect.

Comment: To expand on David's comment (using a 32 bit vector): `or_result <= '0' when input=X"00000000" else '1';`
Change the number of zeros to match the length of the vector in question.

Comment: Logic reduction is available in vhdl 2008, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20296276/and-all-elements-of-an-n-bit-array-in-vhdl

Comment: Also you can use more general way: `result <= '0' when (example=(example'range=>'0')) else '1'; `

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`or_reduce` is what you want, and it is available in `std_logic_misc`. Supported by both A and X for FPGAs.

Comment: `and_reduce` is the other useful one.

Answer (score 5):

Verilog has a convenient "reduction operator" that does exactly what you're asking for: `|example[23:0]` gives the result of OR'ing all the bits of the `example` vector.

Unfortunately VHDL doesn't have this operator. According to the [comp.lang.vhdl FAQ](http://www.eda.org/comp.lang.vhdl/FAQ1.html), though

> There is no predefined VHDL operator to perform a reduction operation on all bits of vector (e.g., to "or" all bits of a vector). However, the reduction operators can be easily implemented:
>
> [skipping an example that doesn't handle 'X' and 'Z' values]
>
> ```
>     function or_reduce( V: std_logic_vector )
>                 return std_ulogic is
>       variable result: std_ulogic;
>     begin
>       for i in V'range loop
>         if i = V'left then
>           result := V(i);
>         else
>           result := result OR V(i);
>         end if;
>         exit when result = '1';
>       end loop;
>       return result;
>     end or_reduce;
>     ...
>     b <= or_reduce( b_vec );
> ```

Comment: Is this synthesizable?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, of course, it can be synthesized to a really big OR gate (or a tree of smaller ones). Possibly the version in the standard library (in Aaron D. Marasco's answer) will be better optimized than something generated on the fly.

Comment: VHDL-2008 does have unary reduction operators. The FAQ is outdated. Furthermore, the presented function is of questionable synthesizability because of the early exit which some tools may choke on and isn't necessary other than as a micro-optimization for simulation.